# Lightswitch + WCF RIA + MySQL connector/Net almost working but not quite

Tags: mysql, wcf-ria-services, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm trying to connect to an existing MySQL DB from Lightswitch RTM through a WCF RIA service.

I did the following:

- **Install MySQL connector** version 6.3.7 from MySQL developer zone on my development machine. The lastest version 6.4.3 does not seem to work and gives an error "Out of sync with server" when establishing a connection from within Visual Studio.
- Test the connection from Visual Studio by creating a new data connection, selecting MySQL database as provider, and providing the MySQL server IP address, the user name and password.

This works and the DB shows up correctly.

Then I followed the tutorials [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dbd951/7414/) to use create a WCF RIA service:

- Add a new project to the solution based on the template **WCF RIA Services class library**.
- Add an **ADO.NET entity data model** to the WCF RIA Web project and using the wizard connect it to the MySQL database. The generated connection string is
  `metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string="server=10.192.xx.yy;User Id=xxxxxxx;database=projet;password=xxxxxxxxxx;Persist Security Info=True"`.
- Add a **domain service** to the WCF RIA Web project.

This works correctly. The entity diagram shows the three selected tables of the database with all fields.

Then I connected the WCF RIA service to lightswitch following this tutorial [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/getting-started-root-quickstart-vs-light-switch-wcf-ria.html):

- In the Lightswitch project, create a **new data source** and attach it to the WCF RIA service
- Add a **reference to the WCF RIA Web project** and select the required data source objects. This works and the data source objects are correctly imported.
- Finally copy the connection string from the WCF RIA Web project file App.config to the file web.config in the server generated project of the Lightswitch project. The line is:
  `<add name="b70821ef-..." connectionString="metadata=res:///Model.csdl|res:///Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string="server=10.192.xx.yy;User Id=xxxxxxx;database=projet;password=xxxxxxx;Persist Security Info=True"" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>`

The solution can be built without errors. However, when running the Lightswitch application, the details screen for the MySQL table only shows a red cross and indicates that it cannot load the data.

I suspect that the connection string pasted to web.config is wrong.

**What is wrong/missing in the above approach or how can I isolate and debug the problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this post.
http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Forum/tabid/63/aft/89/Default.aspx

For me it was the solution-> see the last point about config of coonection string

regards