# Connect to MySQL on webhost with Silverlight

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, silverlight

On my webhost I have a MySQL database. In Visual Studio I want to make a Silverlight application (VB.net) that can connect with that database.

How to do this? I found only tutorials for local data.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982624/lightswitch-wcf-ria-mysql-connector-net-almost-working-but-not-quite) is also the answer to yours.
http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Forum/tabid/63/aft/89/Default.aspx

The aim is not to get the Silverlight client communicating with MySql. Instead, you must host a web service that deals with data access. RIA Services does most of the leg work for you.